# Maxima: Differentiate sum at specific index-position

Tags: maxima

In Maxima 12.04.0 I have a sum

```
mysum : sum(u[i]^2, i, 1, N);
```

now I differentiate it

```
diff(mysum, u[i]);
```

now I specify a defined index i=A to differentiate it at

```
at(%, i=A);
```

Unfortunately maxima won't replace the u[i] in the sum that way.

How can I bring maxima to a result like

```
2*u[A]
```

Comment: Any activity on this? Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After you differentiate, push the 2 into the sum, pick out the i-th term, and then substitute i=A:

```
(%i1) mysum : sum(u[i]^2, i, 1, N);
      diff(mysum, u[i]);
      intosum(%);
      part(%, 1);
      %, i=A;
```